# Como imprimir de un DataGrind la celda actual en la que estoy parado

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Estoy usando este codigo pero no sirve

```
private void imprimirCeldaToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            r = new imprimirmanifiesto();
            int pos = 0;
            bool a = true;
            try
            {
                r.imprimir(dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value.ToString());
            }
            catch (Exception q)
            {
                //MessageBox.Show("Verifique número de importación y seleccione un tipo");
            }
        }
```

Metodo para imprimir

```
public class imprimirmanifiesto
    {
        public void imprimir(string dobleslash)
        {
            Process p = new Process();
            p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
            {
                FileName = "C:\\Users\\bodega\\Documents\\Manifiestos\\" + dobleslash + ".pdf",
                UseShellExecute = true,
                Verb = "printto",
                CreateNoWindow = true,
                WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
                //Arguments = printer,
            };
            p.Start();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Podrías compartir el codigo del metodo imprimir, para ayudarte de una mejor manera.

Comment: Hecho, actualizada

Comment: Ademas de eso podrias proporcionar el error?

Comment: No imprime al no encontrar el documento solo se para, por eso necesito imprimir por celda

Comment: Cual es el contenido de las celdas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para obtener el valor de la celda sobre la que tienes la selección, debes usar el siguiente código:

```
DataGridView1.Rows[DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index].Cells[DataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString();
```

Pudes, por ejemplo, asignar ese resultado a una variable tipo `string`, o imprimirlo en un `MessageBox`.

En tu caso, deberías tener el `try` de la siguiente manera:

```
try
{
    r.imprimir(dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index].Cells[dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias.